Is it standard practice to use square brackets for the argument function of a functional?
The Wikipedia page for the functional derivative uses square brackets for notating the argument $f$ of the functional $J$, i.e. $J[f]$, as opposed to $J(f)$. Is it standard practice to use square brackets here instead of parentheses?

Why does this matter?

I'm writing my PhD thesis and wan't to follow convention, if there is one

Yes, it is. Although all conventions are made upon agreement, it’s still handy to type, say, $Jf$ if the functional yields scalar field.

Thanks. Sounds like an answer... would you care to turn your comment into an answer?

If I were writing my PhD thesis, I wouldn't base notation conventions on what happens to get the first comment/first few upvotes on Math StackExchange; I would base it on what's most popular in the papers that cover similar topics that I've been reading.

I commonly see square brackets when one frequently uses parenthesis to surround the arguments of the functions, but if you are just analyzing $J$ as some functional on an abstract function space and make little use of the actual arguments inside the function then it is not uncommon to just use parenthesis
